# C program calculate average

Tags: c, logic

the average is not correct for this code. How to solve the average with this code. I try all of things but every time its same. It shows last number average only.

```
    #include<stdio.h>
void compute(int anumber,int *max,int *min,float *average,int count);

int main ()
{
    int max=0,min=100;
    float average=0;
    int number,i=0;


    printf("\nenter a number:");
    scanf("%d",&number);
    while(number>0){
        i++;
        compute(number,&max,&min,&average,i);
        printf("\nenter a number:");
        scanf("%d",&number);
    }
    printf("\naverage %.2f",average);
    printf("\ncount %d",i);
    printf("\nmin %d",min);
    printf("\nmax %d",max);

    return 0;

}
void compute(int anumber,int *max,int *min,float *average,int count)
{
    float total;
    total=total+anumber;

    *average=total/count;
    ++count;
    if(anumber>*max)
       *max=anumber;
    else if(anumber<*min)
       *min=anumber;
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Issue #1:** Total and number are uninitialized.

In C no initialization of variables is done for you. What is the value of total after:

```
float total;
```

The answer: Whatever was in memory at the location it was allocated. It could 0, 20, 94, 15, 7, or -2.3 billion, unless **you** give it a value it has an arbitrary one. It's value is indeterminate.

```
total=total+anumber;
```

By adding anumber to an unknown number you have no idea what total will become.

**Issue #2:** You don't calculate total.

The total is calculated by taking all the numbers in a set and summing them.

I.E. With the numbers 2,4,6 the total is 2 + 4 + 6 which equals 12. The first thing you should note is the presence of repetition. The addition is a common aspect that can be abstracted. We normally abstract repetition into a loop i.e.

```
int i;
float total = 0;
for(i = 0; i <= 6; i+=2)
{
     total += i;
}
```

You need a similar loop in your program.

Your compute function is void, it cannot return a value. There are a handful of ways to fix total so that you may calculate the average.

1. Define total in the global scope for example, this is done by moving it **outside of any function body**. You'll have to remove the definition of total from within your function, as the variable in the closest outer scope will be used.
2. Make total static, it will not be automatically disposed of between each function call. This allows you to pass in values and allow the total to remain.

Regardless of your choice you'll have to make some changes, as of now you are not actually calculating the average. Further details on the assignment or task you were given would benefit everyone. C has few keywords but many ways of using them, in order to fully answer your question we must know:

1. What is the program supposed to do? Anticipated input/output helps a lot. In order to come up with a solution you must first fully understand the problem. It can be a challenge to extract intended functionality even from well written and working code, it can be near impossible to do so with broken code.
2. Were you given specifications? Do you understand them? I see from your comment that you are not allowed to change function headers/prototypes, what other restrictions do you have?

One final note. I'm assuming this is a homework assignment, as someone who has taken many classes based around C programming and who has taught some myself I can guarantee you - You will get the most out of the exercise by receiving only the help that is necessary, strive to think about the problem as much as you can on your own as well.

Answer (score 0):

Your variable "total" is local to the compute() function, so it does not contain the total of all the input numbers - it is as new variable each time compute() is called, which is every time through the loop.

If you want to process each number one at a time, you can find the total within the compute function, if you make total a global variable. Then the correct approach would be find the average once, by dividing that total by the number of values.

Comment: Can i write "total" as a local variable? I dont want to use this variable in to the compute() function. compute() function must be "void compute(int anumber,int *max,int *min,float *average,int count)" only.